# Set Values for other columns in gridview based on selected value of dropdownlist inside gridview(edit mode) in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have gridview with Employee Name, Emp Code, Designation. I am populating Employee Names dropdownlist with values in rowdatabound event. In **edit mode** of, on selection of a value in Employee Names dropdownlist, the EmpCode and Designation should change accordingly. The empCode and Designation label controls are in templatefield. I have writtern selectionchanged event for the Employee Names drodownlist,

```
ddlEmp.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(grd_ddlEmp_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

but I do not know how to change Emp Code and Designation values inside the particular row in gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does these things inside the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `DropDownList`

1. First find the row.
2. Then access the controls and change accordingly.

Pseudo Code

```
protected void grd_ddlEmp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView row = ((DropDownList)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    Label Designation = row.FindControl("id of the designation label") as Label;
    Designation.Text = "new Designation Name";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your gridview in **UpdatePanel** and do it in code behind of **SelectedIndexChanged** event like I have done in datalist below :

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlstPassengers" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dlstPassengers_ItemDataBound"
 RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="2" Width="100%">
 <ItemTemplate>
       <div class="form-linebg" style="line-height: 32px;">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged"
CssClass="select-3" Style="width: 145px; margin-bottom: 9px;" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" CssClass="select-3" Style="width: 145px; margin-bottom: 10px;"
runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

In code behind :

```
protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DropDownList ddlCountry = (DropDownList)sender;
                DropDownList ddlCity = (DropDownList)((DropDownList)sender).Parent.FindControl("ddlCity");
                BindCity(ddlCity, ddlCountry.SelectedValue);
            }

    private void BindCity(DropDownList ddlCity, string countryCode)
            {
    // Binding code of city based selected country
    }
```

You need to set EmpCode and Designation columns on SelectedIndexChanged event of dropdown by finding control in code behind.

Comment: I am able to get only dropdownlist's value, I am not able to access any other columns in gridview using Parent.FindControl from sender. Naveen's solution worked out! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the SelectedIndexChanged function, find the selected value of the drop down box

```
  DropDownList ddl = (GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex].FindControl("DropDownList1") AS DropDownList);
  var selectedVal = ddl.SelectedValue;
```

Execute some code to determine the Emp Code and Desgination and then populate the relevant label ( or other control):

```
Label lbl = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex].FindControl("Label1") as Label;
```

Assign value to the label.

Answer (score 0):

use in your dropdown  **AutoPostBack="true"**